# Why does selecting an item from the sidebar of NavigationSplitView crashes after deleting an item?

Tags: swift, swiftui

These are the very simple and exact steps to reproduce the crash.

1. Select 'Southern Ocean' (the last item on the list)
2. Delete 'Southern Ocean' from the sidebar using a swipe action.
3. WITHOUT SELECTING 'Arctic Ocean', delete 'Arctic Ocean' with swipe action.
4. Select another ocean and the app crashes.

Note: I even tried using basic custom types with an id property of type UUID, but the crash still happens.

Why does the crash happen? Is it due to the selection or something?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection: String?
    
    @State private var oceans = ["Pacific", "Atlantic", "Indian", "Arctic", "Southern"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(oceans, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { ocean in
                NavigationLink(value: ocean) {
                    Text(ocean)
                        .bold()
                        .swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: false) {
                            Button(role: .destructive) {
                                let index = oceans.firstIndex {
                                    $0 == ocean
                                }
                                
                                if let index = index {
                                    oceans.remove(at: index)
                                    selection = nil
                                }
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: "trash")
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
        } detail: {
            if let selection = selection {
                Text(selection)
                    .bold()
            } else {
                Text("Choose from the left")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an error message in console when it crashes? Which one?

Comment: No error message in console. Just a very generic Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1059895f8) crash.

Comment: cannot replicate your issue, followed the 4 steps and all
 works well for me, no crash at all. Tested on real devices iPhone (ios17) and Mac Catalyst (not Previews).
 I'm on MacOS 14, Xcode 15, it could be different on older systems.

Comment: Have updated my original post. It apparently only causes the crash among very specific rows...

Comment: yes I can now reproduce the crash on iPad (ios 17) with the new 4 steps.

Comment: it seems to work for me if I replace `selection = nil` with `selection = oceans.first`

Comment: Using `id: \.self` in a `ForEach` with a swipe to delete can often cause crashes. Try using an identifiable struct and not a String here.

Comment: @Yrb, that does not work either. I've tried it
 (just like Apple example: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list)
 and the crash still happens. No crash for me if I use `selection = oceans.first`

Comment: Did you try to add the swipe action to the navigation link (ie the list element)

Comment: It is listed as a known issue in iOS 17 beta 4 release notes

Comment: @SwiftEnthusiast Have you found a solution to this issue? I think I'm facing the same and it does not seem to be fixed yet...